# Do one needs to follow his own Dharma Sutra or all Dharma Sutras?

Tags: dharma-shastras

I have read that there are many Dharma Sutra like Apasthamba Sutra, Gauthama Sutra, Baudhyana Sutra,etc. My question is that Do we need to follow only his own Dharma Sutra got by birth or all of the Dharma Sutra?

Comment: Let's follow our Dharma sutras. If something we need is not mentioned in our Sutra ( Mine is Apastamba), we will search in other dharma Sutras.

Comment: Own sutras are first preferences